# How get the return of AsyncTask and put on a edittext in the activity?

Tags: android, api, android-asynctask

Im studying android, and i want to make an app that connects to a service and gets the values from there..

**main activity:**

```
public class teste extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new api().execute();
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class api extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {           
            URL url = new URL("https://randomuser.me/api/0.7");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String linha;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(linha);
                buffer.append("\n");
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dados) {

    }
}
```

how can i fill a `EditText` in the `mainactivity` with the values returned from the asynctask?

Ive searched in the web, but cand find a answer that works..

thankss!

Rafael

Comment: is this class api in your teste class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide code for your EditText view, consider the following piece of code and modify accordingly to suit your case. You need to write the following on the `onPostExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String dados) {
    EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText); //replace here with your editText's id
    simpleEditText.setText(dados); //dados contains the result returned from the doInBackground() method
}
```

**EDIT**

I now realised that the `api` class is in different file from the `teste` class, so you need to pass a reference of the latter one (the activity) to the `AyncTask`, `api`. You can do this by declaring a constructor:

```
public class api extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private Activity activity;

    //constructor
    public api(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    //rest of your code


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dados) {
        EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText); //replace here with your editText's id
        simpleEditText.setText(dados); //dados contains the result returned from the doInBackground() method
    }

}
```

and call your `api` in `teste`:

```
public class teste extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new api(this).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually AsyncTask are used as InnerClasses inside your MainActivity class so that, like @pleft said, you can use the provided code in onPostExecute.

As a beginner I will suggest you to look at this very great tutorial from Udacity https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851

Comment: I also suggest you to study AsyncTaskLoader (Loaders) and some nice libraries like Retrofit and RxJava. It's very important to have strong roots knowing many alternatives to solve problems. And... I don't like AsyncTask so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  The point of an AsyncTask is its asynchronous.  It doesn't return anything.  You should never call .get() on one, if you do then there's no point in using an AsyncTask.  Instead, all the code that needs the result should be placed in onPostExecute.

Comment: So could you help me to find a solution? I just need to call a service and put  the results on a EditText... :)

Comment: You do it in onPostExecute.  If necessary, you put up a waiting UI until the asynchronous call is finished

Comment: Could you show me how to do this? Because how can i access the edittext of the screen in the onPostExecute?

Comment: If its an inner class, access it directly via the variable you save it to.  If its a normal class, pass it in as a parameter to the constructor and save it there.